# How do I "generify" a closure type alias in Swift?

Tags: ios, syntax, swift, closures

In order to make my code easier to read, I am using type aliases in Swift for various types of closures. I have the following basic set of closures:

```
public typealias FailureClosure = (error: NSError?) -> Void
public typealias ProgressClosure = (progress: Float32) -> Void
public typealias BasicClosure = () -> Void
```

I would like to add a closure `typealias` that supports generic arrays, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for it. This is as far as I am able to get, but I get the compile time error "***Use of undeclared type 'T'***"

```
public typealias ArrayClosure = <T>(array:[T]?) -> Void
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Or even if it is possible?

Comment: One detail I'd like to point out is that you can define that `typealias` in classes where `T` is defined. If `T` is a generic type of your object, you can create and use `typealias`es like normal inside that class. A note if you do this: outside the class, the `typealias` is not defined, so they will still see the full closure syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. If it *were* possible, the syntax you'd expect would be:

```
public typealias ArrayClosure<T> = (array:[T]?) -> Void
```

You would then use it like `ArrayClosure<Int>`. But it's not currently legal.

That said, I don't really recommend these type aliases. They obscure more than they illuminate. Compare this signature:

```
func foo(onError: FailureClosure)
```

with:

```
func foo(onError: NSError? -> Void)
```

To save just a couple of characters, you force the caller to guess what `FailureClosure` passes. The `error` or `progress` tags don't really help you (you still need to use `progress in ...`).

The one case that makes a lot of sense is around `progress`, but I think the type you want there is:

```
public typealias Progress = Float32
```

Don't get me wrong here, type aliasing can be very helpful when it creates a new *type*. `Progress` is a type that happens to be implemented as as float. But much of what you're doing (definitely with `ArrayClosure`, and to a lesser extent with the others) is just creating new syntax without creating a new type, and that is more often confusing than helpful.

---

To call out your specific example, and why overuse of type aliases can cause you to overcomplicate your design:

```
func foo(failure: ((error: NSError?) -> ())? = nil)
```

You're right that this is really complicated. Compare:

```
func foo(failure: NSError -> Void = {_ in return})
```

Two big changes here. There's no reason to have a failure block that takes an optional error. Always pass an error (if there's no error, why would `failure` be called?). And there's no reason for the failure block to be optional. If you really want a default value, just make the default value do nothing. Two optionals gone, and all the consuming and implementing code gets simpler. Always think carefully about whether something absolutely must be optional. Optionals add a lot of complexity; don't add them lightly.

Personally, I'd probably do this with an overload instead in many cases:

```
func foo(#failure: NSError -> Void) { ...  }

func foo() {
  foo(failure:{ _ in return })
}
```

I just think it's a little easier to understand what's going on. But either way is fine.

---

EDIT (Dec 2014): After writing Swift for a few more months, I've grown more fond of @David's approach in the comments below, which is to use an optional for the closure, but not for the error. Particularly given Swift's optional chaining syntax (`failure?()`), it often does wind up being clearer.

```
func foo(failure: (NSError -> Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. From your examples it makes sense that using type aliases for closures is basically just creating new syntax, I do think it makes code more readable. Take this function for example: `func foo(failure: ((error: NSError?) -> ())? = nil)`, it is fairly tricky to understand what's going on here, not to mention all the brackets and syntax. Hence the use of a `typealias`. Unless you can suggest a simpler method of declaring such a method.

Comment: In your example, there's no need for an optional. I'd probably recommend using overloads here rather than a default value, but you can just make your default value be a closure that does nothing, especially since it returns `Void`. That will simplify your later code as well. Nesting things in typealiases encourages these kinds of complicated signatures, which then are hard to actually use in many cases. (We saw this a lot with really complex blocks in ObjC.)

Comment: It is true that if you have a very complex type, and really need that type, and use that type often, it is worth creating an alias for it. But that shouldn't become your normal pattern. As you see, it runs into lots of little corner-cases where it doesn't even work.

Comment: Great answer, I wasn't really expecting so much in-depth advice. Thanks!

Comment: To offer a contrasting opinion on making the failure block an optional, I think it really does preserve the intent much better to make it optional than to make it required with an empty default.  It explicitly says to the user "You can get (optional) error information if you want it." It really doesn't complicate your code, since you can use optional folding and it just works out as `failure?(error)`  I do agree that typealias should be used judiciously and that there's no reason for the error argument to be optional, since it by definition really must be present.

Comment: After a few more months of writing this stuff, I've grown to agree with @David's comment. Edited.

Comment: Generic type aliases would be really handy when it comes to passing the same closure around like million times.

Comment: You were spot on on the syntax - Swift 3 supports generic closure aliases the way you do in your first snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.1 supports generic type aliases. You can use this feature to provide a name for function with generic parameters.

You may have to use such declaration:

```
public typealias ArrayClosure<T> = ([T]?) -> Void
```