# typealias generic function

Tags: function, generics, swift

As a learning exercise I'm trying to write a small functional library. Many of the functions in my library require a function to be passed in. I would like to "typealias" this function so that the user of my library has to pass in a function with a specific signature.

I've tried this:

`typealias Callback = Result<AnyObject> -> ()`

This kind of works but I would like the `AnyObject` part to be *anything*. Not specifically `AnyObject`, since that's actually some kind of real type(?). My `Result` enum i based on this [article](http://owensd.io/2014/07/09/error-handling.html) about error handling in Swift. It's a generic enum, so that's what I want to reflect in my function signatures.

If I remove the `<AnyObject>` part I get an error saying:

> Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in <...>

And if I just to `Result<T>` I get the error:

> Use of undeclared type 'T'

As far as I've understood it it's not possible to typealias generics. So.. is there away around this?

TLDR;

I have a bunch of functions that I want to take a function of a specific signature as a parameter, in my case:

`(result: Result<T>) -> ()`

How do I force this?

Comment: As @natecook notes, this isn't currently possible, but we also just discussed almost the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909856/how-do-i-generify-a-closure-type-alias-in-swift/25912041#25912041

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 4.1 supports generic type aliases. You can use this feature to provide a name for function with generic parameters.

You may have to use such declaration:

```
typealias Callback<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, there's no way to have a typealias be generic ([language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_592)), but you can still include your method signature in a function definition, it's just a little messy:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure
}

func printResult<T>(result: Result<T>) {
    switch result {
    case .Success(let value):
        println(value)
    case .Failure:
        println("failure")
    }
}

func doSomething<T>(value: T?, f: (Result<T>) -> ()) {
    if value != nil {
        f(Result<T>.Success(value!))
    } else {
        f(Result<T>.Failure)
    }
}

doSomething(21, printResult)
// 21

// can't do this, since type inference for the generic
// Result<T> doesn't work on just `nil`:
// doSomething(nil, printResult)

let noString: String? = nil 
doSomething(noString, printResult)  // now calling as doSomething<String>
// failure
```

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood. I was unclear, I'll update my question. But basically I just want to force the _signature_ of the function. I want the user of my library to be able pass in _any_ function with _any_ function body.

Comment: The `doSomething` function is exactly that -- its second parameter will take any function that has one `Result<T>` parameter and returns `Void`. `printResult` was just one example.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. I've already figured that out. What I want to do, if possible, is to take that `f: (Result<T>) -> ()` and make that be `f: Callback` to avoid having to write the first one over and over! Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Yeah, no can do, since type aliases can't themselves be generic.

Comment: I know I don't _need_ it, but it'd be neat if I _could_ do it. I have ~20 functions that all take the same callback. Other then saving me lots of typing upfront it'll save me tons of work if I have to change the callback.

Answer (score -1):

Here i am presenting example for **typealias in swift 2.0** that shows how to use **typealias** in protocols definitions: i hope this helps you understand typealias in swift 2.0

```
protocol NumaricType {

typealias elementType

func plus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType

func minus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType
 }


struct Arthamatic :NumaricType {

func addMethod(element1 :Int, element2 :Int) -> Int {
   return plus(element1, element2)
}
func minusMethod(ele1 :Int, ele2 :Int) -> Int {
    return minus(ele1, ele2)
}

typealias elementType = Int

func plus(lhs: elementType,  _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
    return lhs + rhs
}
func minus(lhs: elementType, _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
    return lhs - rhs
 }
}
```

Output:

```
     let obj =  Arthamatic().addMethod(34, element2: 45) // 79
```